# How esp used to reach function Arguments

Tags: assembly, x86

As i know in win32, when a function called the Process memory layout be like this:

```
High Memory Addresses
+-----------------+  <- Higher addresses
|   Arguments     |  <- Arguments pushed by the caller
+-----------------+
|   Return Address|  <- Return address pushed by the CALL instruction
+-----------------+
|     Old EBP     |  <- Saved EBP of the calling function
+-----------------+  <- Current EBP points here
|   Local Vars    |  <- Local variables of the function
|     and/or      |
|   Temporaries   |
+-----------------+ ----> ESP point Here .>>
Low Memory Addresses
```

so esp will point to the last block on stack as mentioned above.

i saw in many articles that they use esp + 0 , esp + 4 and so to reach function arguments and ret address . how can this done ?
i mean in windows32 i know each block on stack use 4 bytes , so if the stack want to use functions arguments must use 4byte(ebp) + 4byte(return address) then can reach arguments .

so

```
exp + 0 not ret address
esp + 0 is ebp
esp + 4 is ret
```

i know im wrong but can anyone correct me.

Comment: there are 2 different i386 asm syntaxes (same nemonics but different syntax)... and they differ in how they represent offsets
you can google for examples, or take my first googled example
https://imada.sdu.dk/u/kslarsen/dm546/Material/IntelnATT.htm

Comment: Parameters do not have to be passed by the stack

Comment: @GradyPlayer , i dont see anything related to esp and arguments

Comment: @gulpr , what do you mean ? can you explain more .

Comment: It's usually EBP that's used to access the parameters, but ESP can be used too. The basic idea is - **the compiler knows how big all those blocks are** and can calculate the offsets (i. e. differences) from the current value of ESP to the place where the argument is.

Comment: Note that "old ebp" and "local vars" are put on the stack by the called function. The `esp + 0` is return address, `esp + 4` is first arg only applies at function entry. If `esp` is subsequently moved, for example by setting up a stack frame, you need to adjust the offsets.

Comment: parameters can be also passed in the registers - how many will be passed in registers depends on ABI

Comment: @Jester but why does they start calculate the offset before function prolog ? i mean if we push the ret address to stack and stop then yes esp + 0 is ret address , but does stack work like that ?

Comment: Yes, it does. E.g. you can make a function to add two numbers as: `mov eax, [esp+4]; add eax, [esp+8]; ret`. Now if you want to set up a stack frame, e.g. by `push ebp` then you need to adjust the offsets by 4. If you also have locals or otherwise manipulate `esp` you need to account for those changes as well. The point is to free `ebp` for general purpose use since x86 has relatively few registers. (PS: the return address is put on the stack by the `call`.)